# A list of predefined groovy variables

Tags: syntax, groovy

I'm new to groovy and I'm wondering where can I find a full list of predefined
groovy variables like *it* and *delegate*?

The particular thing that I'm interested in is if there are predefined keyword for
the reference to the object from where the current method was invoked, for example:

```
5.times { print 5 - it}
```

with the use of such keyword it should be something like:

```
5.times { print *keyword* - it }
```

so the question is what's the *keyword* should be used there?

**P.S.:** another example:

```
MyObject myObject = new myObject();
myObject.getField(); // MyObject has method named getField
myObject.doJob ({ 
    ...
    ((MyObject)*keyword*).getField(); // instead of myObject.getField();
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a good list of all actual keywords (which are fewer than you'd think) and object-level properties that are like keywords, this article is really good: http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/09/groovys-special-words.html

If you have control over the `doJob` method in your example, then you should set the `delegate` of the closure:

```
def doJob(Closure closure) {
    closure.delegate = this
    closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    // loop or whatever
    closure()
}
```

Now, in your closure, you can reference any properties on the parent object directly, like so:

```
myObject.doJob ({ 
    ...
    getField()
    ...
})
```

[Groovy Closures - Implicit Variables.](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures#Closures-this,owner,anddelegate)

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for this?

```
int number = 5
number.times { print number - it }
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: the example in my question is simplified, so it is ok to do as you suggest for this particular example but I need a keyword that does exactly the thing that I wrote in my question

Comment: of course, maybe there are no such a predefined variable, but I hope to find one

Comment: According to documentation there is no such keyword. Take a look at this link: http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Number.html#times%28groovy.lang.Closure%29

Comment: this is documentation about Number, but my question is rather general, I added another example to my question to clarify it, take a look